# Waiting for Completion block and control reaches end of non-void waiting for async

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I would like to implement a BOOL function with two layer of async completion block

```
  __strong auto weakSelf = self;
  [_functionA complete:^{
    __strong auto strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
        [strongSelf functionB:param1 complete:^{
          return self->_property1;
        }];
    }}];
```

It will complain "control reaches end of non-void function"; but I cannot add a default return otherwise it will return that value first without waiting for the functionB finished. And it becomes harder when there are two wrap of completion block here.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Meaning of

```
control reaches end of non-void function
```

Is that :

> The compiler cannot tell from that code if the function will ever
> reach the end and still return something.

You have non-void method which is missing `return` in any of `if-else` condition.

By looking at your code It looks like you used block to return `BOOL`. that is not possible because your function and blocks executes in different scope.

Check if it helps:

```
__strong auto weakSelf = self;
    return [_functionA complete:^{
      __strong auto strongSelf = weakSelf;
      if (strongSelf) {
          return [strongSelf functionB:param1 complete:^{
            return self->_property1;
          }];
      } else {
          return YES;
      }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a `semaphore` to wait until the async code finishes.

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
BOOL result = false; // default value

__strong auto weakSelf = self;
[_functionA complete:^{
  __strong auto strongSelf = weakSelf;
  if (strongSelf) {
      [strongSelf functionB:param1 complete:^{
        result = self->_property1;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
      }];
  } else {
      dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
  }
}];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_release(semaphore);

return result;
```

Comment: You could freeze UI among other problems if you `dispatch_semaphore_wait` on main thread so that comes with a caveat.